# Python- If statement to handle queue output not correctly handling all outputs

Tags: python, if-statement, queue

I receive data updates via a queue, in order to determine whether the update is an updated order(s) or updated market price(s) I need to run an if statement, which looks to see which custom class is being received. This works fine, I can see the correct classes are being received and the if statement (or at least this part) works correctly.

Where I am struggling is that I have 2 functions, one that updates the orders and puts them in a format to feed into a second function, which then formats the market data (with orders) and outputs in a readable format.

The functions themselves work correctly, in that if I plug in the expected data, I get the correct outputs...however I am struggling to get my head around receiving the data correctly, as this appears to be causing the problem.

```
while True:
    combined_books = market_queue.get()
    order_books = []
    market_books = []
    for y in combined_books:
        print(y)
        if isinstance(y, MarketBook):
            market_books.append(y)
            time_stamp = datetime.now()
            print(time_stamp, "Running for: ", time_stamp - start_time,
                  "======================================================")
            update_market_book(market_books, mb, uo, market_catalogues, mkt_runners, profitloss, trading, False,
                               start_time, eo)
        elif isinstance(y, CurrentOrders):
            order_books.append(y)
            uo = update_orders(order_books, mkt_runners, profitloss, trading, eo, mb)
            time_stamp = datetime.now()
            print(time_stamp, "Running for: ", time_stamp - start_time,
                  "======================================================")
            update_market_book(market_books, mb, uo, market_catalogues, mkt_runners, profitloss, trading, False,
                               start_time, eo)
        else:
            print('Its all gone horribly wrong: ', y)
```

So, what happens is as follows:

1) If I receive a market data update, the update_market_book function is triggered and this works correctly.

2) If I receive an order update, this is correctly identified, but doesn't update the market_book (i.e. of the 2 functions, update_orders fires, but then there is no market_books to populate the first variable of the update_market_books function and hence it simply shows a blank).

3) When the next market data update comes through, the previous orders show correctly.

So in essence, what I'm not understanding, is why in this section:

```
        elif isinstance(y, CurrentOrders):
            order_books.append(y)
            uo = update_orders(order_books, mkt_runners, profitloss, trading, eo, mb)
            time_stamp = datetime.now()
            print(time_stamp, "Running for: ", time_stamp - start_time,
                  "======================================================")
            update_market_book(market_books, mb, uo, market_catalogues, mkt_runners, profitloss, trading, False,
                               start_time, eo)
```

market_books is blank, when it has already been populated by a previous update and/or perhaps more importantly, how can I ensure that it is populated with the last updated market_books that (correctly) triggered the first part of the if statement.

Hopefully that makes sense and is probably really simple to a Python expert, maybe its the time of day, but I just can't seem to figure out the logic here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the very first item in `combined_books` is a `CurrentOrders` instance, then `market_books` will be empty.

Comment: That, I can understand (and live with if need be), but what I'm not understanding is why, if market_books is the first item, then CurrentOrders the 2nd, why I draw a blank? Surely market_books exists, CurrentOrders has also been populated, so I should see a result?

Comment: In essence, I want to somehow always take the last market_books and use that whenever a CurrentOrders update comes along (which I thought is what I'd done...but I clearly haven't)!

Comment: What do you mean by _why I draw a blank_? Are you talking about something going on inside your head, or are you talking about something in the code?

Comment: Sorry, must be the time of day, I can't even write properly anymore :-)

I meant, given market_books has already been populated (assuming the first item is a MarketBook) then, when the next CurrentOrders comes along, why is market_books blank, this list surely has already been populated, with the previous append?

Comment: If `market_books` is blank, the obvious explanation is that all of the items you've processed in `combined_books` have been `CurrentOrder` items.

Comment: No, but thats not the case, hence my confusion!

Comment: For example:

Item 1: CurrentOrders -> Blank (makes sense)
Item 2: MarketBook -> Returns result (again makes sense)
Item 3: CurrentOrders -> Blank (this confuses me, as market_books has already been populated by Item 2, so why would this not return a result)?

Comment: Can you add some print messages to the `if` and `else` sections, so you can see exactly what is happening?

Comment: Yep, so in the second code snippet, market_books is [] (i.e. an empty list), everything else is populated as expected. So somehow, even though the list has already been populated, when referred to by the elif statement, it somehow appears as if it has never been populated!

Comment: Have you verified that `market_books` is actually being updated? Are you sure that `combined_books` contains more than one transaction? After all, you have that `while True` there, and no logging code that tells you how many transactions are in `combined_books`. Add some more logging. Or, run the thing in your debugger.

Comment: A fair point about logging code, but yes market_books is being updated (I just verified that with a simple print(market_books) and the same for print(combined_books).

Comment: I think I need to start again, approaching this from a different perspective, will re-post!